# cleaning url with mod rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

Hi apologys if this is somewhere but i can't find an answer that works with my setup.

I have a website where I want to remove the file names from the url so that `www.example.co.uk/products/products.php` becomes `www.example.co.uk/products/`. i have used to following to remove /index.php from the home page but i cant get it to work with files in folders.

here is the working code that removes my index.php from the homepage url how can i modify it to remove products.php etc from my other pages?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

any help appreciated

Comment: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*products\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)products\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] i have change to the above now i get 403 forbidden message when visiting products page

Comment: Revert to the index.php code and then rename products.php to index.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule will apply to every URL pointing to a PHP file, stripping off the latter and issuing a redirect to the remainder.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\/[^/]+\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/[^/]+\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**EDIT**
@Ashley Briscoe: I think you are messing things up here a bit. Say the initial URL your client is requesting is `http://www.example.com/products/products.php`. This will be rewritten by the above rule to `http://www.example.com/products/`.

Since now the rewritten URL is pointing to a directory (the trailing slash indicates that) rather than a file resource, Apache is trying to serve the [directory index file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html) (e.g. index.html or index.php) in case **mod_dir** is being used (we can safely assume it is).

The `403 Forbidden` response you get now indicates that the user your web server is running as DOES NOT have sufficient priviledges to read the directory index file and/or open its containing folder.

To resolve this, you need to make sure that there actually exists a directory index file (thus renaming `products.php` to `index.php` within the products directory) and that the web server has the permission to read that file.

**EDIT 2**
Regarding your last comment: If renaming isn't an option then you would have to let Apache know what file it should serve instead. Thus add another rule, like so:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\/[^/]+\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/[^/]+\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^products/?$ /products/products.php [L]
```

Comment: that works on home page but causes 403 on any other pages which are in folders for example products.php is in www.example.co.uk/products/products.php. it works on my index.php which is at root

Comment: thank you for your quick responses though not sure why it won't work on pages not at root

Comment: @Anish I can't change the page names as I have set my body id to be dynamic so i can target pages with css so changing file names is not an option

Comment: Thank you for your advice guys, I changed the body id to a php variable so i didn't need to name the files for my styles. everything is working fine now cheers. stack overflow is certainly the best site to come to

Comment: @AshleyBriscoe You're welcome. Do not forget to accept and/or upvote helpful answers, though.

Comment: have accepted the answer can't vote yet don't have the rep. One last question with the rewrites i have done can i put in there to redirect from all the previously indexed urls?

Comment: @AshleyBriscoe What do you mean by >>can i put in there to redirect from all the previously indexed urls<<? Could you give an example?

Comment: i have solved it myself thanks for all the help i just added 301 redirects for all the urls google had indexed before i changed them back to index.php

Comment: @AshleyBriscoe Glad, you made it :D